# Function works on first call, but on second call it does not

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have three v-select's, where you can select certain values. All of these should be unique (not at dropdown). I have three arrays for that. The first so that the values ​​in the dropdown are constantly displayed the same (this array is not important for the function). The second which is bound to the respective dropdown with the help of v-model. The third is there to recognize what values ​​I have to exchange, so that all values ​​remain unique. the strange thing is, the first time the function works, but the second time the third array is changed exactly like the second array, which is bound via v-model (it will be exactly the same). However, I change the value of the third array anywhere, except in the function.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select
      v-model="selectedCollections[0]"
      :items="collections"
      label="1. Collection"
      @change="uniqueCollections(0)"
    />
    <v-select
      v-model="selectedCollections[1]"
      :items="collections"
      label="2. Collection"
      @change="uniqueCollections(1)"
    />

    <v-select
      v-model="selectedCollections[2]"
      :items="collections"
      label="3. Collection"
      @change="uniqueCollections(2)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: [String],
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      collections: [
        "Playlist",
        "Screen",
        "Location"
      ],
      selectedCollections: [
        "Playlist",
        "Screen",
        "Location"
      ],
      selectedStaticCollections: [
        "Playlist",
        "Screen",
        "Location"
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uniqueCollections: function (index) {
      var before = this.selectedCollections[index]
      var indexList = this.selectedStaticCollections.indexOf(before)

      var temp = this.selectedStaticCollections[index]
      this.selectedStaticCollections[index] = this.selectedStaticCollections[indexList]
      this.selectedStaticCollections[indexList] = temp
      this.selectedCollections = this.selectedStaticCollections
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Why is the third array changed the second time the function is called?

Comment: Why uniqueCollections function is not wrapped inside methods: {  } property in this component

Comment: @chandrasekar i accidentally deleted to much. now it is in

Comment: Okie I'll check on the same

Comment: your question is not quite clear. Please name your arrays which change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your function you are assigning `array` to `array`. Arrays are `objects` in JS and behaves not as `primitives`. After that assignment both arrays would change if any changes would be made in any of them.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

arr1 = arr2;

arr2[2] = 999;

console.log(arr1[2]); // Will also log 999
```

If you want to copy values but not reference to the array you can use `Array.from()` method:

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

arr1 = Array.from(arr2);

arr2[2] = 999;

console.log(arr1[2]); // Will log 6
```